# How to make a Go dll function that takes a go struct or interface as an argument

Tags: c, go, dll

I am working with go and dlls, and need to create a go dll that exports a function that accepts a go struct.

```
//test.go
package main

import "fmt"

//export TestFunc
func TestFunc(s TestStruct) {
  fmt.Println(s.a)
}

func main() {}
```

```
//teststruct.go
package main

type TestStruct struct {
  a int
}
```

and build with

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o test.dll .\test.go .\teststruct.go
```

I get a perfect dll file.
Now when I use this Go code to call it

```
//testcall.go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    l, e := syscall.LoadLibrary("test.dll")

    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    p, e := syscall.GetProcAddress(l, "TestFunc")

    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    _, _, _ = syscall.Syscall(p, 1, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&TestStruct{
        a: 1002,
    })), 0, 0)
}
```

and run with

```
go run .\testcall.go .\teststruct.go
```

I get a fatal error:

> The specified procedure could not be found.

When I do the same in C, it works fine:

```
//test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "struct.h"

__declspec(dllexport) void TestFunc(struct TestStruct s) {
    printf("%d\n", s.a);
}
```

```
//testcall.c

#include <windows.h>
#include "struct.h"

int main() {
    HINSTANCE l = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
    FARPROC p = GetProcAddress(l, "TestFunc");
    struct TestStruct s;
    s.a = 1002;
    p(s);
}
```

```
//teststruct.h

struct TestStruct {
    int a;
};
```

and build with:

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -shared -o test.dll test.o
gcc .\testcall.c
```

I don't get any error, and it gives me

> 1002

In addition, if I use `import "C"` in my test.go file, it will give me

> unrecognized Go type TestStruct

and that should happen, because C does not know what that type is. So is there any way to use a go struct as a parameter, and why is it giving me a `procedure not found` error?

Comment: Which statement fails? Also note that your function takes its argument by value but in your call you're passing a pointer.

Comment: `syscall.GetProcAddress` is failing. (I put a dummy print statement to check)

Comment: I also tested by taking a `*TestStruct` instead of a `TestStruct` parameter, but it also fails.

Comment: You're not importing "C", so it's not building the export. You can't export a Go type, because the interface is C, not Go.

Comment: Is there a way to force Go to build an export without the import "C"? Or a way to allow go to accept go types when importing "C"?

Comment: The only way to interact with the shared object is via its C api, so there's no such thing as a "go type" in that context.